# VSTGUI Standalone Build

Tags: c++, vst

Can anybody point me in the right direction for building my VST as a standalone executable?

The SDK provides an example, but no real do documentation to explain what exactly is happening.

So far Ive managed to build the SDK, and create my own app (with VSTGUI selected). But how I turn this project into a standalone application is a mystery!

James

Comment: I have no idea what vst is however for packaging maybe you need to use NSIS or WIX to package your executable like you would do for any other c++ project. Although that assumes  you are using MSWindows and not Android, macOS, one of the thousands of linux distributions ...

Comment: https://www.hermannseib.com/english/savihost.htm

Comment: Perhaps write a minimal separate VST host executable and load your VST as a VST.